# Laravel Traer datos del modelo agrupado por meses

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

Hola tengo la siguiente tabla en la BD

```
Fruta 

id | name | precio | fecha_compra
```

quisiera traerme el total de precio de todas las frutas compradas agrupado por meses mediante eloquent o querybuuilder

el resultado que es pero es la siguiente:

```
{
   "Enero" : "338$",
   "Febrero" : "555$",
    ...
    ...
    ...
   "Diciembre" : "100$"
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado hasta el momento?

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado

```
$frutas= Fruta::select(
            DB::raw('sum(precio) as sums'),
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months")
        )
            ->groupBy('months')
            ->get();
```

Comment: hubiera sido genial que en tu pregunta agregaras que usas un campo created_at

Comment: fecha_compra es created_at disculpa

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo la siguiente solución con Fluent el QueryBuilder de Laravel

```
$data = Fruta::
        select(DB::raw("name, mes, SUM(precio) as count"))
        ->groupBy("mes")
        ->orderBy('mes', 'DESC')
        ->get();
    return $data;
```

> Cabe resaltar que como vamos a usar Fluent, en la parte superior
>   tienes que importar el namespace del DB Facade; del modo siguiente

```
use DB;
```

Comment: me da el siguiente error Call to a member function groupBy() on float

Comment: con cual de las 2 opciones @kevinautam

Comment: con eloquent...

Comment: la primera si te sirve o tampoco? @kevinautam

Comment: la primera me da reusltados raros, no agrupa por meses, de hecho me trae los mismos registros

Comment: dame unos minutos para hacer pruebas

Comment: ya lo solucione @alfredopaz gracias